# Preserving double slashes in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have searched everywhere for this answer, and the answers that have been posted do not fit my specific situation as it gives me 404 errors, and I'm not sure why.

I am trying to rewrite this: `/c.php?url=http://www.example.com`

Into this: `/c/http://www.example.com`

Right now I have this in my mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)(/)?$ /c.php?url=$1
```

But when it rewrites the url that I am trying to send into the PHP script, it writes "`http:/example.com`", with one slash instead of the double slash.

I've seen a lot of things posted about this involving the THE_REQUEST rule, but when I try to apply them to my htaccess file, they fail. I am not sure what is wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apache removes multiple slashes inside the path. And as you’re already mentioned, you can solve this by inspecting the request line in *THE_REQUEST*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /c/([^?\ ]+)/?
RewriteRule ^c/ /c.php?url=%1
```

Comment: Thanks, Gumbo. I had to add a + in the /c/([^?\ ]+)/? to allow more than one character, but it works well, though I am new to mod_rewrite and I am having a difficult time trying decipher how the THE_REQUEST command works... 

Also, is there any way to preserve question marks in the URL that is being sent as well? 

Thanks!

Comment: @boomboom: *THE\_REQUEST* represents the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1). And if you want to get the full requested path and query string, it is probably easier to get it in *c.php* from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly.