# Detecting double slash (empty parameter) in request_uri

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, double, slash

Related
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270921/mod-rewrite-and-double-slash-issue)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115646/preserving-double-slashes-in-mod-rewrite)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889435/can-mod-rewrite-preserve-a-double-slash)

But this question is slightly different.

Say I have a RewriteRule like:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([\w]*)/([\w]*)/([\w]*)/?$ go.php?q=THREE_$1_$2_$3
```

So http://localhost/test/a/b/c gets rewritten to http://localhost/go.php?q=THREE_a_b_c

Now say I want to explicitly catch the condition where the middle parameter is left out and a double slash results, like http://localhost/test/a//c

So I write a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([\w]*)//([\w]*)/?$ go.php?q=TWO_$1_(EMPTY)_$2
```

**BUT ALAS**, the rule never matches, it seems RewriteRule *does not see the double slash*, even though the double slash *is* preserved in both `%{THE_REQUEST}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

So I write a rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //
RewriteRule ^test/([\w]*)/([\w]*)/?$ go.php?q=TWO_$1_(NONE)_$2
```

And **that** works, because the RewriteCond only applies if there's a double slash in the REQUEST_URI.  But as you can see I still have to assume there's NO double slash there when parsing with the regex.

All this is very disturbing because I thought RewriteRule worked on %{REQUEST_URI} but it turns out it *doesn't*, it works on something else (a double slash stripped version..?)

My question really is, if not raw %{REQUEST_URI} then what does RewriteRule feed on?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but your second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([\w]*)//([\w]*)/([\w]*)/?$ go.php?q=TWO_$1_(EMPTY)_$2
```

appears to be trying to match a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/test/a//b/c
```

or like this:

```
http://localhost/test/a///c
```

If you change the second rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([\w]*)//([\w]*)/?$ go.php?q=TWO_$1_(EMPTY)_$2
```

it should work.

Edit:

**The real [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831355/diggbar-modrewrite-how-do-they-pass-urls-through-modrewrite/869017#869017)!**

> Apache removes empty path segments

Now I know the issue is not just an incorrect regex, I searched for the answer.

Comment: Error in the post.  But :) That's _what you'd think_ but it actually does not work that way.

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly fair for you to downvote when I wrote what I did solely because of an error you made in your question :/

Comment: I know.  But I only did it to prevent driveby upvotes.  Undone.  But this still doesn't really answer the question which is:  if not raw %{REQUEST_URI} then what does RewriteRule feed on?

Comment: Well, from Gumbo's answer, it appears that RewriteRule feeds on Apache's own internal "normalized" URI which has changes such as the removal of empty path segments.